# Disable radio button group angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I want to disable radio button group using angularjs in a static html page.I am using angularjs material design.
Here is my code

```
<md-input-container>
     <label>Air Conditioned</label> 
     <md-radio-group ng-model="master.airConditioned" name="airConditioned" required ng-disabled="true" class="mdradio radioAlign"  layout="row">
        <md-radio-button  value="true" class="md-primary"> Yes </md-radio-button>
        <md-radio-button value="false"> No </md-radio-button>                                           
    </md-radio-group>
</md-input-container>
```

Comment: do you want to disable all the radio buttons or only particular radio button, if you want to disable the particular radio button you can use ng-disabled="true" in md-radio-button

Comment: I want to disable all the radio buttons

Comment: md-radio-group , has only two attributes ng-model and md-no-ink , ng-disabled is not supported for md-radio-group.

Comment: I actually think it's a bug because you can see that adding `ng-disabled="true"` to the `md-radio-group` changes the styling of the radio buttons to look disabled but doesn't disable them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I got it, Just add  `ng-disabled="true"` for each `md-radio-button`

```
<md-radio-group ng-model="master.airConditioned" name="airConditioned" required class="mdradio radioAlign"  layout="row">
    <md-radio-button  value="true" class="md-primary" ng-disabled="true"> Yes </md-radio-button>
    <md-radio-button value="false" ng-disabled="true"> No </md-radio-button>                                           
</md-radio-group>
```